# Case Insensitivity of MySQL

Tags: mysql, case-insensitive

Hello everyone I am using MySQL 5.0, but when I fire my queries through my web application that is in Java they are case insensitive.

First query:

```
select * from market where company='"abc"'
```

Second query:

```
select 8 from market where company='"ABC"'
```

Both queries give me same results. I just want rows with company "abc" only and not  ABC.

How I can solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binary collation for the field, for instance utf8_bin

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

If you want to do always case sensitive searches on that field, you can use an alter table to set `utf8_bin`, or another binary collation, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE `market` CHANGE `company` `company` VARCHAR( 255 ) 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper collation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html